# Load config of external library in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, application.properties

I have a spring boot application(microservice). 
I have to use an external library within this service.

External Library is as below:

```
public class ExternalConfig {
   private String config1;
   private boolean config2;
}

public class ExternalService {
   private ExternalConfig config;
   public ExternalService(ExternalConfig config) {
      this.config = config;
   }

   public void performSomeAction() {

   }
}
```

Now, this library is not annotated with any spring annotation. And in my spring app, I have a Config and usage as below:

```
public class Config {
   @Value("${abc.config1}")
   private String config1;

   @Value("${abc.config2}")
   private String config2;

   // How do I load the config from the application.properties.
   private ExternalConfig externalConfig;

}

@Service
@ComponentScan
public class ExternalLibraryService {
    private ExternalService externalService;

    public ExternalLibraryService(ExternalConfig config) {
       externalService = new ExternalService(config);
    }
    public void doSomething() {
        .
        .
        externalService.performSomeAction();
        .
        .
    }
}
```

And my application.properties is as below:

```
# ABC Config
abc.config1=value1
abc.config2=value2

# External Config
external.config1=exvalue1
external.config2=true
```

Now how do I load the config to the external library? 
One possible way is to extend the **ExternalConfig** with my spring app and load it. I want to know if there is a way in spring boot to load these.

Answer (score 2):

You could create an `ExternalConfig` as a spring bean.

Something like this

```java
@Bean
public ExternalConfig externalConfig(@Value("${external.config1}") String config1, 
                                     @Value("${external.config2}") boolean config2) {
return new ExternalConfig(config1, config2);
}
```